# Zend_Cache_Frontend_Function, not working

Tags: zend-framework, caching, frontend

I am attempting to use `Zend_Cache_Frontend_Function` to cache some of my own function calls.

The cache is set up like so:

```
$manager = new Zend_Cache_Manager();

$frontendOptions = array(
   'lifetime' => intval(CACHELIFETIME),
   'automatic_serialization' => true);

$backendOptions = array('cache_dir' => CACHEDIR);

$funcCache = Zend_Cache::factory('Function',
'File',
$frontendOptions,
$backendOptions);

$manager->setCache('function', $funcCache);
```

I then use the cache like so:

```
$country_name = "UK";
$country_id = 1;

$country = new Default_Db_Table_Country();
$country = $cache->call(array($country, "getCountryByName"), array($country_name, $id));
```

Even after calling this several times, the function `getCountryByName()` is still being called and the database query within it run.

Am I using this correctly? How can I stop the call to `getCountryByName()` happening multiple times?

Thanks

**Edit:**

Looking at the source, it seems that `call()` uses output buffering, if this is the case then my functions output nothing, they only return objects. Thus making `Zend_Cache_Frontend_Function` useless in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that `Zend_Cache_Frontend_Class` is the way to go and not `Function`. I need to set the class before each call to ensure the right object is being used;

```
$country = new Default_Db_Table_Country();
$cache->setCachedEntity($country);
$country = $cache->getCountryByName($country_name, $id);
```

This Frontend does cache objects, arrays, etc.